# optimization of polyfit on 3D data set

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, loops, optimization

I am trying to implement a non-uniformity correction algorithm on infrared images. Basically I have a set of images of a black body, wich is supposed to be at a very precise and homogeneous temperature. But due to camera hardware (sensor, optics...), the image you get is not homogeneous.
I have images (640*512 pix) at different temperatures (around 10 images from 18°C to 30°C), and I need to correct the values of each pixels, to fit the mean value of the central area (supposed to be the correct value).

So, for each pixel, I need to fit a polynomial function  `p`(order 5):

```
x=p(y)
```

where `x` is the value of the pixel, and `y` is the mean value of the central area.

For now I vectorized my images to avoid double looping, and loop over each pixels :

```
import numpy as np
interp_degree=5
nb_of_pixels=640*512
image =np.random.rand(640,512)
mean_value=np.arange(18,28,1)
a=image.flatten()
DL=np.transpose([a for i in range(10)]) # I simplified up to this point for the example

K=np.empty((nb_of_pixels,interp_degree+1))
for i in range(len(DL)): # loop over each pixels
    K[i]=np.polyfit(DL[i],mean_value,interp_degree) # fitting
    DLC_NUC[i]=np.polyval(K[i],DL[i]) # eval the corrected value of the pixel for later use
```

This loop take about 200 sec on my computer, and I would like to reduce this time. `polyfit` and `polyval` already use multiprocessing, so this is not a way.

Is there ways to improve this?

Comment: To at least get your example code running properly: (1) in your code `nb_of_pixels` is not declared.  is it `len(DL)`?  (2) `instead of DL=np.transpose([a for i in range(10)])` use the following to avoid raising rank warnings from `polyfit` `DL=np.transpose([np.random.rand(640,512) for i in range(10)])`

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the nb_of_pixels. This is an example, in my application I don't use random matrix but real images, so I don't get rank warnings (except for bad pixels, but this is another issue). My question here is more about the way I implemented this, and if there is a better way.